# How to access a CloudSQL read replica if it does not allow to create an ipv4 address

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, ipv4

If i try to create an ipv4 address via the web console it says:

Operation failed: Requested operation is not allowed for a failover replica.

The mysql is a first generation instance.

The master already has an ipv4 address and i can connect to it without problems.

My goal is to provide heavy readings queries (reports) isolated from the master that is constantly in use by the application.

The query readings are done by the client with mysql connector via ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system was affected by an issue in the GCP side. As I can see from my side it was already fixed.

Please, let me know if the issue persists on your side.

Comment: Did you had a similar problem, that is now fixed in your side? or you never had an issue at all.

Comment: I'm contacting Google Product Engineering team. Please let me know if the issue persists on your side, so I can report them.

Comment: Hi @user2277832,

I’m from Google Cloud Platform support team. I have noticed that there was an issue on Google ends at the time of your report regarding “Requested operation is not allowed for a failover replica”, and it's now resolved. Please, let me know if the issue persists on your side, thus I can consult the GCP CloudSQL engineering team and extend my research.